# Error : Native Module RNGeocoder tried to override RNGeocoderModule when I use the react-native-geocoder package in react native

Tags: android, react-native

I am building a React Native application and In this application, I need to get the location of a Particular area that is Street Address, City and Country.

I am trying to use react-native-geocoder package to get this information.

When I follow the tutorial and edit my MainApplication.java, setting.gradle, build.gradle and my codes as;

The link to the tutotiral and github repo of the package
https://github.com/devfd/react-native-geocoder

```
_getLocationAsync = async () => {

    var NY = {
          lat: 40.7809261,
          lng: -73.9637594
        };
    Geocoder.geocodePosition(NY).then(res => {
     this.setState({
       locationObj: res
     });
     console.log(res)
    // res is an Array of geocoding object (see below)
    })
   .catch(err => console.log(err))

    this.setState({
        procesingLocation: false,
    });   
};
```

I get the following Error on screen of my emulator;

***native module RNGeocoder tried to override RNGeocoderModule. Check the getPackages() method in MainApplication.java, it might be that module is being created twice . if this was your intention set canoverrideExistingModule=true***

My MainApplication.java looks has the following codes;

```
import com.devfd.RNGeocoder.RNGeocoderPackage;

@Override
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
  @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
  List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
  // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
  // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
  packages.add(new RNGeocoderPackage());
  return packages;
}
```

Please any help on this will be appreciated.

Comment: I can't solve this problem with my knowledge. I'm sorry.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, with a different package: https://github.com/mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation/issues/406

Answer (score 0):

how about try deleting the following code?

> packages.add(new RNGeocoderPackage());

Newer version of React Native seems to do auto link, which means we don't have to manually add the package again.